# How can one add a blogging engine to their app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

So I've followed the installation instructions on their(KatanaCode's) GitHub (see here:https://github.com/KatanaCode/blogit), however, I am unsure as to what to do next.

In otherwords, the gem is installed and the configurations are available in the config file - albeit, how do I actually go about displaying the blog in the views?

So far, I have the blogit.rb model created with all of the shipped schema but I don't know what to do next.

Please advice!!!